# MongoDB not starting on Mac

Tags: macos, mongodb

I installed `MongoDB` via `Homebrew`. Manually created the `/data/db` directory. Tried to run `mongod` command from Command Line, here's what happened :

```
Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro:~ sanjeetsuhag$ mongod
mongod --help for help and startup options
2014-04-24T09:18:12.949+0530 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=19900 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro.local
2014-04-24T09:18:12.949+0530 [initandlisten] 
2014-04-24T09:18:12.949+0530 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2014-04-24T09:18:12.949+0530 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.0
2014-04-24T09:18:12.949+0530 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2014-04-24T09:18:12.949+0530 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin minimavericks.local 13.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Thu Jan 16 19:40:37 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.90.20~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-04-24T09:18:12.949+0530 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-04-24T09:18:12.949+0530 [initandlisten] options: {}
2014-04-24T09:18:12.949+0530 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2014-04-24T09:18:12.949+0530 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2014-04-24T09:18:12.949+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2014-04-24T09:18:12.949+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2014-04-24T09:18:12.949+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2014-04-24T09:18:12.950+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2014-04-24T09:18:12.950+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2014-04-24T09:18:12.950+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2014-04-24T09:18:12.950+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2014-04-24T09:18:12.950+0530 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2014-04-24T09:18:12.950+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2014-04-24T09:18:12.950+0530 [initandlisten] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
2014-04-24T09:18:12.950+0530 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro:~ sanjeetsuhag$
```

What's going wrong ?

**EDIT**

```
Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro:~ sanjeetsuhag$ ls -ld /data/db
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  68 Apr 24 09:15 /data/db
Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro:~ sanjeetsuhag$ whoami
sanjeetsuhag
Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro:~ sanjeetsuhag$
```

Comment: what is the permissions on /data/db vs who is the user you are starting mongod process as?  If that user doesn't have write permissions to the db directory this will happen.

Comment: do `ls -ld /data/db` and post the results.  Then do `whoami` and post the result of that.  It's not relevant whether the user you are running as has admin privileges or not.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the files `mongod` is trying to write to are owned by `root` but you are running `mongod` as user `sanjeetsuhag`.

The correct fix would be to change ownership of the directory via command:

```
$ sudo chown -R sanjeetsuhag /data/db
```

This will make the directory and everything under it owned by the same user you are running `mongod` as, which will allow it to start.

Comment: sorry, you will need to run it with sudo

Answer (score 2):

I have same issues. I installed MongoDB with homebrew.

I think it needs admin priveledges.

I used : `sudo mongod` and it worked fine for me. Please try it.

Answer (score -2):

{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.380+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.383+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.399+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.406+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.406+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.406+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.406+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.407+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":6806,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"sumanths-Mac-mini.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.407+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23352,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Unable to resolve sysctl {sysctlName} (number) ","attr":{"sysctlName":"hw.cpufrequency"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.407+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23351,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"{sysctlName} unavailable","attr":{"sysctlName":"machdep.cpu.features"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.407+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.1","gitVersion":"32f0f9c88dc44a2c8073a5bd47cf779d4bfdee6b","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"aarch64","target_arch":"aarch64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.407+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"22.2.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.407+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.411+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":5693100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Asio socket.set_option failed with std::system_error","attr":{"note":"acceptor TCP fast open","option":{"level":6,"name":261,"data":"00 04 00 00"},"error":{"what":"set_option: Invalid argument","message":"Invalid argument","category":"asio.system","value":22}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.415+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.415+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.416+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4794602, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Attempting to enter quiesce mode"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.416+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":6371601, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FLE Crud thread pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.416+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.416+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.416+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.416+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.416+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.416+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.416+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.416+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.416+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.416+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.417+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.417+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.417+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.417+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6278511, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the Change Stream Expired Pre-images Remover"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.417+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.417+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.417+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-17T08:43:44.417+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}

service state will start and end like this if we use sudo mongod

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).